# Hide template visibility depending on VS version?

Tags: vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-templates

I have created a VSIX with 2 templates, one is for VS2012 and another is for VS2013.

But if I use the VSIX, both templates are visible for both VS versions in "New Project" window. I want to restrict it. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great solution, but only one I've found for this problem.

You can register your package to initialize early on in the Visual Studio startup with the following attribute.

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
public sealed YourPackage : Package
```

Then in your `override void Initialize()` method you'll want to register a new `DTEEvent`.

```
DTEEvents dte_events;
private void RegisterStartupEvents()
{
    if(dte == null)
        dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));


    if (dte != null)
    {
        dte_events = dte.Events.DTEEvents;
        dte_events.OnStartupComplete += OnStartupComplete;
    }
}
```

The `OnStartupComplete` will fire on startup before any templates have been initialized. To remove them from the list for the current VS version, the bundled `zip` template files that are copied when your VSIX package is installed will have to be **deleted**. This method could probably be nicer, but you get the idea.

```
private void OnStartupComplete()
{
    dte_events.OnStartupComplete -= OnStartupComplete;
    dte_events = null;
    var cleanupList = TemplateCleanupByVsVersion[MajorVisualStudioVersion];
    foreach (var deleteTemplate in cleanupList)
    {
        DirectoryInfo localVsDir = new DirectoryInfo(UserLocalDataPath);
        // Locate root path of your extension installation directory.
        var packageDllFileInfo = localVsDir.GetFiles("MyVsPackage.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0];
        DirectoryInfo extensionDirInfo = packageDllFileInfo.Directory;
        if (extensionDirInfo == null)
        {
            // Failed to locate extension install directory, bail.
            return;
        }
        var files = extensionDirInfo.GetFiles(deleteTemplate + ".zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            File.Delete(files[0].FullName);
        }
    }
    ServiceProvider.GetWritableSettingsStore().SetPackageReady(true);
}
```

`TemplateCleanupByVsVersion` is a `Dictionart<int,List<string>>` that maps Visual Studio Major version with a list of zip file names (without extension) that you don't want showing up in the mapped Visual Studio version. Eg,

```
public readonly Dictionary<int, List<string>> TemplateCleanupByVsVersion = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
        {
            {11,new List<string> { "MyTemplate1.csharp", "MyTemplate2.csharp", "MyTemplate3.csharp" } },
            {12,new List<string> { "MyTemplate1.csharp" }},
            {14,new List<string>()}
        };
```

`MajorVisualStudioVersion` comes from parsing `dte.Version`. eg,

```
public int MajorVisualStudioVersion => int.Parse(dte.Version.Substring(0, 2));
```

The result being specific Visual Studio versions can remove any templates from your VSIX that don't work well. Hope that helps.